# Setting focus on an input element

Tags: angularjs

In the following AngularJS code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

      myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);

  </script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <script>
          function Ctrl($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'Whirled';
          }
        </script>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
          <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-focus=""><br>
          <input type="text" ng-model="place"><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to set focus on the first input element. There isn't an example of this on angular.org and the code above doesn't work. How do you use ng-focus? Does this directive even exist at all?

Comment: that's the event who gets called on focus. so if you have a function as an expression in `ng-focus` your function is executed on focus.

Comment: `ng-focus` doesn't serve that purpose. Either use html5's `autofocus` or write a custom directive.

Comment: My misunderstanding. I thought it was used to set the focus. It's used to catch a focus event.